# Using existing array values to affect MySQL sorting (ORDER BY)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

Say I have a table called artists with these fields (artistid, rank).

Then say I have an array called $rankadjustments with a value for each artist (like 1, 7, 3,-3, 5, 9, etc).

I am doing a MYSQL query that gets the info from artists table and sorts according to the rank field like this...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM artists ORDER BY rank";
```

Easy enough.  But what if I would like to bring that data back sorted by (rank + rankadjustment).  For example, if the artist ranked 1st had a rank of "1" from mysql, but had a rankadjustment of "5" from the rankadjustment array, his "true" rank would be "6".

Again, rankadjustment is NOT a field in my table, otherwise it would obviously be simple.  It's calculated on the fly and stored in an array.

Is there a way to do this IN the query itself? It doesn't seem possible but wanted to find out for sure.  If not, what is best way to do? I assume... Get the data sorted JUST by rank and put it into an array, then create a new array that adds rank + rankadjustment and reorder it?

I guess that wouldn't be too bad but again, wanted to make sure I'm not missing something that would allow me to do it all in the query (or just more efficiently).

Thanks!

Comment: Your rank adjustment array has values for the adjustments.  How do you know what student they belong to?  Also, is this information stored in a table in the database?

Comment: Sorry, the array has an index with their "artistid". For example, $rankadjustment[34][7] would be the artist with an artistid of "34" has a rank adjustment of 7.  And no, the rankadjustments are NOT in a database, just the array.

Comment: big unknown for us is how `rankadjustments` get calculated. If they are in static array then doubtful you can include them in query

Comment: rankadjustment gets calculated by looking at other data from other separate tables (just some averaging of other numbers) and the result of the calculation becomes the "rankadjustment" for each artist, which I put into an array.  Someone at work recommended I create a TEMPORARY database table, but not sure that's the way to go.  Sorry if that doesn't clear things up at all :(